# My App crashes when I navigate to my speedtest screen

Tags: react-native

[image]My app gets closed as soon as I click on my speedtest screen.This is my code. It runs well in debugging mode. But the screen does not open in the release version(apk). These are the packages I am using for this component.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  Modal,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import {NetworkInfo} from 'react-native-network-info';
import Ping from 'react-native-ping';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import RNSpeedometer from 'react-native-speedometer';
import {measureConnectionSpeed} from 'react-native-network-bandwith-speed';
import Speedometer from 'react-native-cool-speedometer';
import {AppFont, Color} from '../components/Constatnts';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import WifiManager from 'react-native-wifi-reborn';
import {AUTH, LOGIN_URL} from '../components/APIs';
import axios from 'react-native-axios';
import {Detail} from '../components/Token';
import {UserId, Token} from '../components/Token';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import StyleSheet from 'react-native-media-query';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess maybe module import from 'react-native-gesture-handler',
ex: import FlatList from 'react-native-gesture-handler'. it work on debug but die with release in some case. or try import 'react-native-gesture-handler' in  App.js or index.js .
For the most accurate, you need to open android studio, select build variant chosse release, select error log and filter with pakage name [image]

Comment: Thanks, @Viết Kenji Gi I will try it. here is the link for screenshot while I opened my android folder In android studio. What should I do? All of theme are in debugging state
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuF4s.png

Comment: you have teamview? i can check for u :D.

Comment: you need drag apk release to simulator , open logcat in android studio, select your  bundle name. filter error, when your app crash bug show in here,